# How to implement custom filebrowser into tinyMCE 4.2.5

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've been reading a lot of questions and answers here at this awesome community. Some really saved me hours of "coding try and error". Thanks for that.

Now my problem:
I am customizing my tinyMCE 4.2.5 running on my webserver. I want to have a custom filebrowser where I upload my and select the files to insert into the editor.
But something is not working there probably. These are my code snippets:

**editor initiation (editor.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    tinyMCE.init({
       theme: "modern",
       width: 800,
       height: 500,
       selector: 'textarea.editor',
       plugins: "colorpicker fullscreen hr image imagetools link lists searchreplace textcolor textpattern wordcount youtube vimeo imgdrop",
       toolbar1: "undo redo | cut copy paste searchreplace | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image | fullscreen | youtube vimeo | imgdrop",
       toolbar2: "formatselect fontsizeselect | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | hr bullist numlist outdent indent blockquote",
       menubar: false
    });  
});
</script>
<form method="post" action="draft.php">
<label>Title</label><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($title)) { echo $title; }?>" />
<label>Author</label><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php if(isset($author)) { echo $author; }?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if(isset($id)) { echo $id; }?>" />
<textarea name="content" class="editor"><?php if(isset($content)) { echo $content; }?></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Klick" onClick="this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

**custom filebrowser (dropzone.php)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#pix a').bind('click', function(){
      var img_url = $(this).attr('data-img-url');
      tinymce.activeEditor.selection.setContent('<strong>Some contents</strong>');
      top.tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
});

});
</script>
<div id="pix">
<?php
$response_type = 'php';
$pic_dir = $path;
include('../pixlie.php');

foreach ($pixlie_table_file as $picture){ 
    $picture['link_get'] = str_replace("?q=","?q=".$pic_dir, $picture['link_get']);?>
        <a href="" data-img-url="<?php echo $path."/".$picture['name'].$picture['extension']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $pixlie_table_env['path_pixlie'].$picture['link_get']; ?>_x<?php echo $picture['extension']; ?>" 
        alt="<?php echo $picture['name']; ?>" />
        </a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

**tinyMCE plugin (imgdrop)**

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('imgdrop', function(editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('imgdrop', {
        text: 'PIX',
        tooltip: 'Insert Pictures',
        icon: false,
        onclick: function() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'Insert Pictures',
                url: 'upload/upload.php',
                width: 700,
                height: 600
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The idea is to open the plugin (imgdrop) as a modal Popup and then select the file I want to insert by clicking on it. (Then window should close then and the data inserted where the caret is placed in the editor).

I hope anyone can help me with this issue here. I've been trying since a few days but nothing seems to work.
Needless to say that I am not a coding expert.

Cheers
Tim